# Excel not showing formula result on sheet, but F9 shows correct value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working on an excel sheet and I've encountered an issue I've never come across before. I'm trying to sum the results of an array function, but I'm not getting any results from the sum on the sheet - just blank cells. The weird part is when I press <kbd>F9</kbd> in the formula bar it shows the correct summed value that should show in the cells on the sheet. I just don't get why the value would appear in the formula bar, but not in the cells on the sheet. Other forums mentioned changing the calculation option (on automatic of course) or to 'show zeros', which just changed the cells to zero instead of blank. <kbd>F9</kbd> still shows the correct value. Here's the formula:

```
{=SUM(OFFSET(INDIRECT("Sheet1!E"&IF(ISERROR(MATCH($A$2:$A$15&$C$1,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$51,0)),
1000,MATCH($A$2:$A$15&$C$1,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$51,0))),0,ROW(1:1)))}
```

The match gets me the row index for the numbers I need to sum. (E1000 is just a default for when there isn't a match and references a cell with 0 in it). If I remove the sum from the function and use <kbd>F9</kbd> I can see the actual array with the numbers to be summed. This is what is so confusing to me. Everything seems to evaluate correctly, it just doesn't show on the sheet. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Being an array formula are you committing the formula by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

Comment: Yes, it seems to evaluate fine. Like I mentioned, I get the result I expect in the formula bar with F9.

Comment: Did you set the cell format to general?  Have you tried putting a anything else in that cell to see if something displays?  If you moved the equation, and associated data to a new spreadsheet does it still behave the same?  does it still behave the same after restarting excel?  after restarting your comp?  I've had excel start to do weird things on me until I reboot.  does not happen often.

Comment: Yes, tried putting just a simple formula in the same cells, showed up fine. Also I moved the equation to another sheet and had the same issue. I manually formatted the cells to general and to number with no change in behavior. And yeah even when as far to restart both the program and my comp. Also saved it in a bunch of different formats with no change. At this point I found a work around, but I still would like to figure out why it was behaving so weird.

Comment: I am able to duplicate the problem. It seems SUM doesn't play well with INDIRECT.

Comment: Really? Well at least that's a little less disheartening than me doing something wrong. I ended up just doing it in VBA. When they get that complex I find native excel to be more frustrating than not.

Answer (score 4):

I know this thread is a couple months old, but for anyone having this issue, try checking for Circular References. It is likely that your formula has at least one.

To check: click the Formulas tab, click the arrow next to Error Checking, point to Circular References, and then click the first cell listed in the submenu.

Reasoning: When using the Evaluate Formula function (F9), it only does a one time calculation and is able to give a complete result. However, if a circular reference is present, the formula in the sheet itself will continuously recalculate so may never have a definitive result.

Comment: I'd be willing to bet this answers OPs question. Helped me after a lot of looking for sure.

Comment: This fixed my issue too. Really appreciate it! :)

Comment: For me Circular References is disabled. The formula works fine in MAC but not on windows.

Answer (score 1):

I came here because I had the same issue, and the above did not initially work for me.

I found that to execute the array function you must highlight the entire formula and then (for Mac) press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Once I did this it worked like a charm!!

Comment: This fixed my issue!  I'm rapidly ascending in my Excel technical abilities due to a big project I'm working on, so I didn't know array formulas need to be surrounded by {}'s

Answer (score 1):

Try "Recalculate All" on the formulas tab.

This solved a similar issue for me with an AVERAGEIF function, whose value would show up correctly in the formula viewer, but not in the sheet. Forcing the sheet to recalculate everything fixed the problem in my case.

The problem seems to occur when defining a cell that is based on another cell, that is based on other cells, that are based on other cells, that are based on other cells...at some point Excel seems to give up and assume that there's a circular reference somewhere, even though there isn't in my case.

When Excel calculates all sheets, it re-uses results, and ignores cells until their precedents are known, rather than working backward from a particular cell, so it doesn't freak out if a cell relies on too many preceding cells.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem, very frustrating. I have found an insane solution. I don't know why it works but it does... I thought that I would try the formula in another cell. So I copied and pasted the cell in another cell... And the formula in the original cell worked and the correct value appeared.

Comment: Really? This was an issue I had some time ago, and came to the conclusion that offset and indirect might be incompatible in certain instances.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem when using **SUMIFS** with three queries on an array. I found the solution was to encapsulate the whole function in brackets. I think the problem must arise from the order in which excel evaluates the constituents of the formula when it derives its answer.

So for example I had to add the following brackets [highlighted in bold] =

```
SUMIFS( [00_COMBINED_NO_DUPLICATES.xlsx]COMBINED!$CK$2:$CK$60067,
        [00_COMBINED_NO_DUPLICATES.xlsx]COMBINED!$F$2:$F$60067,
        [@RR1],
        [00_COMBINED_NO_DUPLICATES.xlsx]COMBINED!$S$2:$S$60067,
        ">="&[@[Quarter_Starting]],
        [00_COMBINED_NO_DUPLICATES.xlsx]COMBINED!$S$2:$S$60067,
        "<"&EOMONTH([@[Quarter_Starting]],
        2
      )+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me. I solved it by pressing Ctrl and '
OR you can go to View, and unselect Show formulas.

In 'normal' Excel Ctrl+' would insert the data from the cell above.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Make Calculate option as automatic. It should solve the probelem
[See the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyNA8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to reopen this but here is a new solution.

I do have circular references, deliberately, so I set Excel to allow them to evaluate only once. Default is OFF - do not evaluate, hence why your formulae returned false / 0 every time even if they appeared true.

To switch on Iterative calculations (i.e. do something with circular references instead of nothing): File -> Options -> Formulas -> Enable Iterative Calculations -> Change from 100 (a little excessive except in special applications) to 1.

Link (scroll down to the bit about iterative calculations): https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/remove-or-allow-a-circular-reference-8540bd0f-6e97-4483-bcf7-1b49cd50d123

Hope this helps some more folks!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is a problem if you are using arrays with OFFSET or INDIRECT.
You can solve it using =N(INDIRECT(... or =N(OFFSET(

You can find the explanation below

[Array Formula Confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47529513/array-formula-confusion)

Answer (score 0):

Many of us have old ways to correct the formula, but let me tell you something: The iterative formula which shows correct results using "F9" means that you do not have to check the formula again and again.

You also do not have to check except the type="general" - that's it.

Now please please, please allow FILE>OPTIONS>FORMULAS>ENABLE ITERATIVE CALCULATION, maximum iteration = 300 (assuming you have 300 cells for iteration), maximum change = 0.001.

This is because we have to check whether the iteration is allowed or not. Hope your problem gets solved.

Answer (score 0):

This problem also occurred when using an excel table reference. Converting the table to normal cells fixed it. Alternatively, changing the references from table to normal references fixed it too.

This part of a formula caused a #value / #wert error

```
VERGLEICH(LF5;DATWERT('Inzidenz RKI_20211129.xlsx'!Table6[[#Kopfzeilen];[27.09.2021]:[26.11.2021]]);0)
```

This did not:

```
VERGLEICH(LF5;DATWERT('[Inzidenz RKI_20211129.xlsx]LK_7-Tage-Fallzahl-aktualisiert'!$C$3:$C$173);0)
```

(vergleich is match, and datwert is datevalue in german excel, and it uses ; instead of commas)