# Array Formula Confusion

Tags: arrays, excel, formula

I am struggling with an array formula, that logically seems sound, however it doesn't appear to be working correctly.  I have been working on a complex sheet, that is not to include VBA, which has made it formula heavy, and using arrays instead.

In the image below, the first part is the problem, for the data shown in columns A-F, I wish to get a sum of the values that match the values in I1:K1.

The formula I have used to begin with can be seen in the first image also, this evaluates, pressing F9, to give me the desired output 20,40 & 50.  However when I add the `SUM` around the formula, I only get the first result out.

I think this is an issue with me not seeing the wood for the trees on this one.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this question is useful for future readers but could do with a better title. Perhaps something like “SUMIF with array criteria”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This array formula seems to work:

```
=SUM((IFERROR(MATCH(A1:F1,I1:K1,0),0)>0)*A2:F2)
```

Answer (score 3):

There are probably multiple better formulas to achieve the same thing.

But to talk about why this fails:

It is because of the [OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) returns a reference rather than a value. And so used in this array formula it returns an array of references `{B2,D2,E2}` instead of an array of values `{20,40,50}` which leads to the problem.

If you are using:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET(A2,0,MATCH($I$1:$K$1,$A$1:$F$1,0)-1))
```

then using Evaluate Formula, you will get:

```
SUMPRODUCT({#VALUE,#VALUE,#VALUE})
```

in next to last step and 0 as the result. So the `OFFSET` leads to error values because of it returns an array of references which will not be dereferenced automatically and so will become `#VALUE` error each.

If you are using

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(OFFSET(A2,0,MATCH($I$1:$K$1,$A$1:$F$1,0)-1)))
```

then it works and returns 110. So the `N` dereferences the references of each `OFFSET` and so the whole formula leads to an array of values `{20,40,50}` in sum.

```
{=SUM(N(OFFSET(A2,0,MATCH($I$1:$K$1,$A$1:$F$1,0)-1)))}
```

works too.

These problems occur using funktions like `OFFSET` and `INDIRECT`, which returns references rather than values, in array formulas. And having a dereferencing function around the `OFFSET` or `INDIRECT` stops the problems.

It is the same with:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INDIRECT("R2C"&MATCH(I1:K1,A1:F1,0),FALSE))
```

versus

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(INDIRECT("R2C"&MATCH(I1:K1,A1:F1,0),FALSE)))
```

Comment: I don't understand why just being volatile means it doesn't evaluate at every step? Also, when OP uses evaluate they seem to see the right values (rather than `#VALUE`)?

Comment: @CallumDA: Pressing `F9` is not the same as using Evaluate Formula. By pressing `F9` you get `{20,40,50}` for the `OFFSET` part. But nevertheless, the whole `SUMPRODUCT` results in 0 and the Evaluate Formula shows why.

Comment: @CallumDA - the OP does not use `SUMPRODUCT()`. If `SUMPRODUCT()` was used then the `#VALUE` is achieved through the evaluation.

Comment: Ah - I didn't notice OP was using F9, my bad. Shame we don't know more about why volatile functions do what they do... :(

Comment: @AxelRichter Cool answer. I've recently learned about the usefulness of the `N` function but I never really fully understood what it was doing. Out of curiosity, do you know if `N` itself is volatile?

Comment: My understanding is that the problem is more to do with the fact that OFFSET normally returns a range rather than a value, when you supply an array as the column argument in OFFSET then the result is an "array of ranges". N function in this case will "de-reference" the ranges. Other functions that can evaluate such an "array of ranges" are typically functions that only accept ranges, e.g. COUNTBLANK, COUNTIF and SUBTOTAL

Comment: @barry houdini: Thank you. Yes, this makes total sense and is a better explanation for the behavior. I have updated my answer. Feel free providing your own answer, then I will delete my answer.

Comment: No need to delete a good answer. I am glad I asked the question though, thanks @barryhoudini for your input.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 if it is a question then N doesn't seem to be volatile.